# Code First Entity Framework Lazy Loading Not Working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm having trouble getting lazy loading to work.

If I do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    using(var db = new BlogContext())
    {

        //db.Blogs.Load();
        //db.Posts.Load();

        foreach (var v in db.Blogs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Blog: "+ v.Name+" Post count:"+v.Posts.Count()); 

        }
    }
}
```

"Post count" is ALWAYS 0;

BUT if I uncomment the Load() calls before the foreach, the Post count is correct. Any ideas what's wrong?

Here's the entity classes being used:

```
   public class Blog
    {

       public Blog(){
          Posts = new List<Post>();
       }
       [Key]
       public int BlogId { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

   }

   public class Post
   {

      [Key]
      public int PostId { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public string Content { get; set; }

      public int BlogId { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("BlogId")]
      public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }

   }


   public class BlogContext : DbContext
   {
      public BlogContext()
      {
         Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
         Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
      }
      public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: You did the relationship mapping?

Comment: Lazy loading should be working for your example but it would cause select N +1 for this case.. better keep it eager

Comment: I am using the code-first approach so the entity and context classes above define the DB and the relationships.

Comment: Just for checking, what happens if you use `db.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts)`?

Comment: If I add db.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts); before the foreach...same thing :-(

Comment: Then somehow the association is broken. Is your code the "whole code and nothing but the code" or did you leave out stuff for brevity?

Comment: I was able to run @user3564870 code without a problem.

Comment: That's all the actual code. But perhaps it's because I'm running in the IDE with a local DB instance? I'm going to setup JF with SQLite and see if it makes a difference. Thanks for all the comments!

Comment: Added the actual main() method to make it more clear

Comment: What version of [tag:entity-framework]?

Comment: Problem was the local MS SQL local DB. I used SQLite without issue. Thanks for everyone's comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was using a local MS SQL database. Using SQLite doesn't have the issues.